# Exporting spark dataframe to .csv with header and specific filename

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, export-to-csv, databricks

I am trying to export data from a spark dataframe to .csv file:

```
df.coalesce(1)\
  .write\
  .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
  .option("header", "true")\
  .save(output_path)
```

It is creating a file name "part-r-00001-512872f2-9b51-46c5-b0ee-31d626063571.csv"

I want the filename to be "part-r-00000.csv" or "part-00000.csv"

As the file is being created on AWS S3, I am limited in how I can use os.system commands.

How can I set the file name while keeping the header in the file?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it matter what it's called on HDFS if you can pull it down and name it whatever you like? `hadoop fs -cat path/to/output/part-r-* > path/to/local/file.csv` will dump all the parts from Hadoop into one file on your local disk.

Comment: I'm trying to build an automated pyspark etl job, hence I'm avoiding all sorts of manual and local system interventions. my ask is simple 'when exporting data from a spark data frame to .csv file, the file name should be 'part-00000'. appreciate your response.

Comment: I've never seen this type of filename before. Maybe the file already exists and this long name was made to avoid overwriting the file?

Comment: no, I did cleanup the target folder and reran the job. that didn't help.

Comment: AFAIK, the file name is `part-#{partition number}-#{random uuid}-#{something}`. AFAIK, the UUID is to allow multiple executors to write to the same directory without worrying about trying to write to the same file.

Answer (score 9):

Well, though I've got -3 rating for my question, here I'm posting the solution which helped me addressing the problem. Me being a techie, always bother more about code / logic than looking into grammar. At least for me, a small context should do to understand the problem.

Coming to the solution:

When we create a .csv file from spark dataframe,

The output file is by default named part-x-yyyyy where:

1) x is either 'm' or 'r', depending on whether the job was a map only job, or reduce
2) yyyyy is the mapper or reducer task number, either it can be 00000 or a random number.

In order to rename the output file, running an os.system HDFS command should do.

```
import os, sys
output_path_stage = //set the source folder path here
output_path  = // set the target folder path here
//creating system command line
cmd2 = "hdfs dfs -mv " + output_path_stage + 'part-*' + '  ' + output_path + 'new_name.csv'
//executing system command
os.system(cmd2)
```

fyi, if we use rdd.saveAsTextFile option, file gets created with no header. If we use `coalesce(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(output_path)` , file gets created with a random part-x name. above solution will help us creating a .csv file with header, delimiter along with required file name.

Comment: Hey dude, sorry people dinged you for grammar. That's bad behavior on their part.

Comment: Hmm. Shoot. I came across your question and was hoping to be able to set it, rather than use commands to rename on the filesystem. Time to go digging!

Comment: It's not looking like it's possible with the libraries as-is, but people point to this for more info about adding this functionality: https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#How_do_I_change_final_output_file_name_with_the_desired_name_rather_than_in_partitions_like_part-00000.2C_part-00001.3F

Comment: Would you be able to locate the output file and rename it? e.g. use `glob` to get the file and then rename or create a copy of it with the intended filename?