# PySpark: Converting a Temporary View to a Table and save as .CSV in local drive

Tags: python, pyspark

I am creating a temporary view of a `JDBC` query in PySpark 2.4. My data source is `MS SQL Server 2017`.

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc").options(url="url",properties = { "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" },dbtable="dbtable").load()
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_temp")
```

Now I can query the temporary created table as

```
df_new = spark.sql("select * from df_temp where ...#standard query")
```

Now I want to write the above `df_new` as `CSV` in my local drive. One way (and currently I am doing the same) is to convert that `df_new.toPandas()`. And then save it as `csv` (standard `df.to_csv('/path/file.csv'` method). This method is creating a  folder named `file.csv` and within this folder a csv file is generated with name that starts with `part-00000-fd4c62bd-f208-4bd3-ae99-f81338b9ede1-c000.csv`.

So if I run my `.py` file on a daily basis (using a scheduler like `crontab`) this is definitely not a good choice.

Questions:

1. How can I standardized the name of the .csv file and on daily basis I can append new data to the same file?
2. Is there any easy way to convert `df_new` to a Table or `Spark DataFrame`. So that I can apply `df.coalesce(1).option("header","true").csv('/path/myfile.csv')`?

Comment: `df_new` is a data frame and therefore you can do `coalesce(1)` and save to the local path.

Comment: I am getting error as 'NoneObject has no attribute write`.

Comment: @pythondumb, you can only specify the foldername where you will write the files to. You cannot control the name of the json file which you are creating. Refer to this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41990086/specifying-the-filename-when-saving-a-dataframe-as-a-csv

Comment: @Gladiator: Assuming I use python equivalent techniques (as mentioned here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48652050/exporting-spark-dataframe-to-csv-with-header-and-specific-filename)In that case how can I append new data to the same file on daily basis?

Comment: I am not sure why exactly you want to have single file, since it affects parallelism and not the best practice. However, there are many techniques. You could try,
1. Move all current data to a temp location
2. Read this temp location and coalesce(1) and write to destination

Comment: @Gladiator: If I do not have a single file, then how can I append on  a daily basis

Comment: You can use 'mode=append'. Refer to the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217724/how-to-append-to-a-csv-file-using-df-write-csv-in-pyspark

Comment: @Gladiator: Thanks!! Will try this as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to save to local filesystem

```
    #for Output in multiple files:
    df.write.option("header", "true").csv("/path/output.csv")

    #for output in single file:
    df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv("/path/output.csv")
```